# Python Selenium headless mode Chrome not pasting the text copied from "Copy Link" button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

For a little context, I am trying to scrape all links to posts from LinkedIn for a given username.
I've tried using different LinkedIn scraping libraries but those did not work, so I turned to Selenium to automate the process.
Given someone's LinkedIn post wall, you cannot 'click' on the posts; the only way to access the post is by opening an extra menu and clicking the 'copy post' button. This does not cause issues in non-headless mode with tkinter. Yet, whenever headless is enabled, it seems to lose access to the clipboard. There is no error message.

I've experimented with window size, copy-paste libraries, different driver options to no avail.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import tkinter as tk
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("web_drivers/chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=options
                          )
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys(email)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys(password)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']"))).click()
link = f"https://www.linkedin.com/in/reidhoffman/recent-activity/all/"
driver.get(link)  # Connect to the endpoint

time.sleep(5)  # wait for the whole page to load
time_to_wait = 1
for n in range(3): 
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
   time.sleep(time_to_wait)
   # Scrolling throught the whole page to make sure that all posts are loaded
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4);")
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3);")
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight*3/4);")
   time.sleep(time_to_wait)
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")

buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "feed-shared-control-menu__trigger")
for button in buttons:
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -100)")
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "option-share-via"))).click()
   driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
   root = tk.Tk() 
   url = root.clipboard_get() # gets nothing
```

Here is the screenshot from the headless driver confirming that it was indeed pressed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Post a [mre]. Did you try [the new headless mode](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/#:~:text=In%202021%2C%20the%20Chrome%20team,t%20display%20any%20platform%20windows.)?